# How to manually set an attachment in a post?

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, library

[image]

I need to manually set an attachment in a estate post with custom php.

When it was the wordpress that inserted the image into the media library, this image appears in the post on frontend.

However, when the user inserts this attachment into the database even the url of an existing image, the image does not appear in the post.

[image]

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: check out the `_wp_attachment_metadata` row in that table.  You would need to change data there as well.  However, in general it's not ideal to be changing attachments via the database, if there's any way to avoid changing images this way I suggest you look into that

Comment: @mrben522 so if I do not have the line "_wp_attachment_metadata" the image will not be rendered?

Comment: yes, you really should be doing this in PHP since that's serialized data.  manually changing it is going to be painful